# Modify height of a ListView inside an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am building an AlertDialog to show a menu where the user can select the country where his mobile phone number belongs.

An example of the list is somehting like this:

```
-----------------------------
|        PHONE PREFIX       |
|                           |
|  Spain           -  0034  |
|  United Kingdom  -  0044  |
|  France          -  0033  |
|---------------------------|
|  CANCEL         ACCEPT    |
|----------------------------
```

and so on...

I have created a list_view item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_listview_pais"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="United Kingdom"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_listview_guion"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_listview_prefijo"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_listview_pais"

        android:text="0034"

        />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also the layout I want for the AlertDialog which is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                >
                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:id="@+id/input_turno_dialog_listview_prefijos">

                </ListView>

            </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

At some point on my activity, I press a button and inside the actionbutton event I call a PrefijosDS which give me an ArrayList to populate the adapter. 
Prefijo class is like this:

```
private String Country;
private String Prefijo;
```

so a Prefijo object can be something like this:

```
Prefijo prefijo = new Prefijo("Spain","0034");
```

With my PrefijoDS I get an Array so I get the data I need. Then, I call the AlertDialog like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.input_turno_dialog_listview_prefijos);
                PrefijoDS prefijoDS = new PrefijoDS(getApplicationContext());
                ListaPrefijosAdapter prefijosAdapter = new ListaPrefijosAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                prefijosAdapter.set((ArrayList<Prefijo>) prefijoDS.obtenerPrefijos());
                lv.setAdapter(prefijosAdapter);

                alertDialog.show();
```

It works, I get the AlertDialog shown but the height of the ListView is very small, almost the height of a single row item. What I want is resize height a bit so it can show 3 or 4 items on the list and then the rest can be scrolled. I tried different ways to make a highest AlertDialog but every time I get the same size. The only way I get an AlertDialog bigger is when I don't use the ScrollView. However, this turns into a very big AlertDialog which I don't want.

I've tried to do this:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(200,300);
```

but then result is a resized AlertDialog but the ListView remains the same. 
How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change the ListView's `layout_height` to `match_parent`, and remove the ScrollView. You can also get rid of one of the RelativeLayouts in the list item layout.

Comment: I did what you said. Now I have an AlertDialog with a Listview inside, but problem is dialog is as big as the whole screen. Is there a way to make it a bit samller?

Comment: Set an exact height measure on the LinearLayout. Or change it's `layout_height` to `wrap_content`, and set an exact height measure on the ListView. Also, if you're not going to add any more Views in the LinearLayout, you don't really need it.

Comment: it works! Cheers Mike!

Answer (score 2):

Change Alert Dialog Size

```
 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
Dialog d = adb.setView(new View(this)).create();
// (That new View is just there to have something inside the dialog that can grow big enough to cover the whole screen.)

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
d.show();
d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

And  one more thing change list view layout_height and layout_width to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="50"
         android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/input_turno_dialog_listview_prefijos">

            </ListView>
      </LinearLayout>
      <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_save"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="SAVE" />
</LinearLayout>
```